# How to display texts that contain curly braces

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to display a JSON string using e.g. `sap.m.Text`?

I'm pretty sure it's treating the text as a binding syntax due to the structure of the string `"{...}"`.

I thought there may be a parameter to disable binding allowing any kind of raw text, but looking at the API, I see no such thing.

Here's an example of the issue: http://jsbin.com/zarijedaya/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: For readers using UI5 v1.52 or higher: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60524582/5846045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the setText method which will consider the JSON as a string.

```
new sap.m.Text().setText(json);
```

http://jsbin.com/bonoxavilo/1/edit

Comment: Thanks, that'll do it. Although seems silly not to be able to use the constructor.

Comment: @Lucien Since 1.52, it's possible with `ManagedObject.escapeSettingsValue`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60524582/5846045

Answer (score 0):

Texts with curly braces can be escaped via [`sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.escapeSettingsValue`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject#methods/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.escapeSettingsValue):

```js
new Text({
  // ManagedObject required from "sap/ui/base/ManagedObject"
  text: ManagedObject.escapeSettingsValue(myJSONText)
});
```

From API referece:

> #### `escapeSettingsValue`
>
> Escapes the given value so it can be used in the constructor's settings object. Should be used when property values are initialized with static string values which could contain binding characters (curly braces)

Here is a demo: https://jsbin.com/bocuzaz/edit?js,output

---

#### Prerequisite

In order to make `escapeSettingsValue` work, bootstrap setting `compatVersion` needs to be set to `"edge"`.