# problems with curly and square bracket in SAPUI5-TextArea

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I read different texts from the backend and display them in a textarea on the dialog when you klick on a button. As far as it works, until I get a text like this **"text{test:[123]}"**. At that point I get an error, because it will interpreted as a binding or array.

Here is my code for the dialog:

```
        var sNotiz = "text{test:[123]};

        var dialog = new sap.m.Dialog({
            title: "Notizanzeige",
            content: new sap.m.TextArea({
                value: sNotiz,
                editable: false,
                growing: true,
                width: "100%"
            }),
            contentWidth: "60%",
            contentHeight: "30%",
            beginButton: new sap.m.Button({
                text: "Schließen",
                press: function() {
                    dialog.close();
                }
            }),
            afterClose: function() {
                dialog.destroy();
            }
        });
```

Is there any way to display these text in a textarea? Or do I have to delete the characters?

Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60524582/5846045

Answer (score 0):

Thanks slezica, that works here too. When I set the text after I had create the Dialog with the TextArea, it works. You have to come up with that first :)

Here the working code

```
        var sNotiz = "text{test:[123]}";

        var dialog = new sap.m.Dialog({
            title: "Notizanzeige",
            content: new sap.m.TextArea({
                id: "test",
                //value: sNotiz,
                editable: false,
                growing: true,
                width: "100%"
            }),
            contentWidth: "60%",
            contentHeight: "30%",
            beginButton: new sap.m.Button({
                text: "Schließen",
                press: function() {
                    dialog.close();
                }
            }),
            afterClose: function() {
                dialog.destroy();
            }
        });

        sap.ui.getCore().byId("test").setValue(sNotiz);
```

Comment: You can assign the text variable directly to the constructor setting property with `ManagedObject.escapeSettingsValue`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60524582/5846045. No need to use `setValue` later on.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the quotes!

```
var sNotiz = "text{test:[123]}";
```

Look at the example:
http://jsbin.com/honiduyaju/edit?js,output

Comment: It's just the question that missed the ending quotation mark (Otherwise the question author would've complained about a syntax error). The real issue is that with `compatVersion="edge"` or `bindingSyntax="complex"`, UI5 parses the text as a binding syntax which results in empty text.

Comment: The sample in your JSBin works since there is neither `compatVersion` nor `bindingSyntax` specified in the bootstrap config. Meaning, the sample will fail if the `sNotiz` is surrounded by curly braces (`"{test: [123]}"`).